# How to Subscribe to Windows File Modification Events

Tags: powershell, events, wmi, wql

I am trying to subscribe to the event of a specific file being modified using `WQL` with this query:

`SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "CIM_DataFile" AND TargetInstance.Drive="C:" AND TargetInstace.Path="\\test\\filewatching\\"`

I can register the event successfully **(see output at the bottom)** and can see it is bound with the script that I registered with (the consumer).

However, when I modify a file in `C:\test\filewatching\` the script does not run.

---

Here is the code for registering for a **File Creation Event** in the same folder, **and this works**:

```
#WQL

$query = @"
SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "Cim_DirectoryContainsFile" AND TargetInstance.GroupComponent="Win32_Directory.Name='C:\\test\\filewatching'"
"@
$instanceFilter = ([WMICLASS]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()
$instanceFilter.QueryLanguage = 'WQL'
$instanceFilter.Query = $query
$instanceFilter.Name = 'EventFilterNameHere'
$instanceFilter.EventNameSpace = 'root/CIMV2'
$result = $instanceFilter.Put()

# Consumer

$script = 
@"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test\filewatching\Log.log", 8, True)
objFile.WriteLine "New File Created"
objFile.Close
"@
$instanceConsumer = ([wmiclass]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer").CreateInstance()
$instanceConsumer.Name = 'ConsumerNameHere'
$instanceConsumer.ScriptingEngine = 'VBScript'
$instanceConsumer.ScriptFilename = '' 
$instanceConsumer.ScriptText = $script
$instanceConsumer.Put()

# Binding

[object]$Filter = (Get-WMIObject -Computername $Computername -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventFilter | Sort Name)
[object]$Consumer = (Get-WMIObject -Computername $Computername -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventConsumer | Sort Name)

$instanceBinding = ([wmiclass]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()
$instanceBinding.Filter = $Filter
$instanceBinding.Consumer = $Consumer
$instanceBinding.Put()
```

So I know there is nothing wrong with my PowerShell. This makes me think that my query must be wrong.

I have tried a few tweaks of the above `InstanceModificationEvent` query, but with no success. (these tweaks include stuff like changing `C:` to `C` or removing `\`s from the `TargetInstace.Path`).

---

I need this subscription to be permanent and it can't reset if the PC is turned on or off - this is why I am using WQL. If anyone can suggest another way of achieving the same or how I can fix my query I will be eternally grateful!

---

**Output after running the script:**

```
Path          : \\WIN7-IT3\root\subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name="Co
                nsumerNameHere"
RelativePath  : ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name="ConsumerNameHere"
Server        : WIN7-IT3
NamespacePath : root\subscription
ClassName     : ActiveScriptEventConsumer
IsClass       : False
IsInstance    : True
IsSingleton   : False

Path          : \\WIN7-IT3\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding.Consumer
                ="\\\\WIN7-IT3\\ROOT\\Subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Na
                me=\"ConsumerNameHere\"",Filter="\\\\WIN7-IT3\\ROOT\\Subscripti
                on:__EventFilter.Name=\"EventFilterNameHere\""
RelativePath  : __FilterToConsumerBinding.Consumer="\\\\WIN7-IT3\\ROOT\\Subscri
                ption:ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name=\"ConsumerNameHere\"",Filt
                er="\\\\WIN7-IT3\\ROOT\\Subscription:__EventFilter.Name=\"Event
                FilterNameHere\""
Server        : WIN7-IT3
NamespacePath : root\subscription
ClassName     : __FilterToConsumerBinding
IsClass       : False
IsInstance    : True
IsSingleton   : False
```

**Querying WMI subscriptions:**

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __Eventfilter
Get-WMIObject -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventConsumer
Get-WMIObject -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __FilterToConsumerBinding
Get-WMIObject -Namespace root\Subscription -Class ActiveScriptEventConsumer
```

**Output after querying:**

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __EventFilter
__SUPERCLASS     : __IndicationRelated
__DYNASTY        : __SystemClass
__RELPATH        : __EventFilter.Name="EventFilterNameHere"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 6
__DERIVATION     : {__IndicationRelated, __SystemClass}
__SERVER         : WIN7-IT3
__NAMESPACE      : ROOT\Subscription
__PATH           : \\WIN7-IT3\ROOT\Subscription:__EventFilter.Name="EventFilterNameHere"
CreatorSID       : {1, 5, 0, 0...}
EventAccess      : 
EventNamespace   : root/CIMV2
Name             : EventFilterNameHere
Query            : SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 5 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 
                   "CIM_DataFile" AND TargetInstance.Drive="C:" AND 
                   TargetInstace.Path="\\test\\filewatching\\"
QueryLanguage    : WQL
PSComputerName   : WIN7-IT3

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : ActiveScriptEventConsumer
__SUPERCLASS     : __EventConsumer
__DYNASTY        : __SystemClass
__RELPATH        : ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name="ConsumerNameHere"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 8
__DERIVATION     : {__EventConsumer, __IndicationRelated, __SystemClass}
__SERVER         : WIN7-IT3
__NAMESPACE      : ROOT\Subscription
__PATH           : \\WIN7-IT3\ROOT\Subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name="ConsumerNameHere"
CreatorSID       : {1, 5, 0, 0...}
KillTimeout      : 0
MachineName      : 
MaximumQueueSize : 
Name             : ConsumerNameHere
ScriptFilename   : 
ScriptingEngine  : VBScript
ScriptText       : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                   Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test\filewatching\Log.log", 8, True)
                   objFile.WriteLine "New File Created"
                   objFile.Close
PSComputerName   : WIN7-IT3

__GENUS                 : 2
__CLASS                 : __FilterToConsumerBinding
__SUPERCLASS            : __IndicationRelated
__DYNASTY               : __SystemClass
__RELPATH               : __FilterToConsumerBinding.Consumer="\\\\WIN7-IT3\\ROOT\\Subscription:ActiveS
                          criptEventConsumer.Name=\"ConsumerNameHere\"",Filter="\\\\WIN7-IT3\\ROOT\\Su
                          bscription:__EventFilter.Name=\"EventFilterNameHere\""
__PROPERTY_COUNT        : 7
__DERIVATION            : {__IndicationRelated, __SystemClass}
__SERVER                : WIN7-IT3
__NAMESPACE             : ROOT\Subscription
__PATH                  : \\WIN7-IT3\ROOT\Subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding.Consumer="\\\\WIN7-IT
                          3\\ROOT\\Subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name=\"ConsumerNameHere\"",F
                          ilter="\\\\WIN7-IT3\\ROOT\\Subscription:__EventFilter.Name=\"EventFilterName
                          Here\""
Consumer                : \\WIN7-IT3\ROOT\Subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name="ConsumerNameHer
                          e"
CreatorSID              : {1, 5, 0, 0...}
DeliverSynchronously    : False
DeliveryQoS             : 
Filter                  : \\WIN7-IT3\ROOT\Subscription:__EventFilter.Name="EventFilterNameHere"
MaintainSecurityContext : False
SlowDownProviders       : False
PSComputerName          : WIN7-IT3

__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : ActiveScriptEventConsumer
__SUPERCLASS     : __EventConsumer
__DYNASTY        : __SystemClass
__RELPATH        : ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name="ConsumerNameHere"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 8
__DERIVATION     : {__EventConsumer, __IndicationRelated, __SystemClass}
__SERVER         : WIN7-IT3
__NAMESPACE      : ROOT\Subscription
__PATH           : \\WIN7-IT3\ROOT\Subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer.Name="ConsumerNameHere"
CreatorSID       : {1, 5, 0, 0...}
KillTimeout      : 0
MachineName      : 
MaximumQueueSize : 
Name             : ConsumerNameHere
ScriptFilename   : 
ScriptingEngine  : VBScript
ScriptText       : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                   Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test\filewatching\Log.log", 8, True)
                   objFile.WriteLine "New File Created"
                   objFile.Close
PSComputerName   : WIN7-IT3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled across [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176631.aspx) soon after posting this question, from which I worked out that the query I need is:

`SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Name='c:\\test\\filewatching\\tester.txt'`

Notice that contrary to several other posts online, what worked for me was actually to omit the `Path` and `Drive` parts of `TargetInstance` and only included the full path and name for the file I want to watch.

This works for me because I will only be watching 1 specific file. If you need to watch multiple files using this method you will need to register multiple subscriptions.

**The full code for registering a File Modification watcher:**

```
#WQL

$query = @"
SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'CIM_DataFile' AND TargetInstance.Name='c:\\test\\filewatching\\tester.txt'
"@
$instanceFilter = ([WMICLASS]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:__EventFilter").CreateInstance()
$instanceFilter.QueryLanguage = 'WQL'
$instanceFilter.Query = $query
$instanceFilter.Name = 'EventFilterNameHere'
$instanceFilter.EventNameSpace = 'root/CIMV2'
$result = $instanceFilter.Put()

# Consumer

$script = 
@"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\test\filewatching\Log.log", 8, True)
objFile.WriteLine "New File Created"
objFile.Close
"@
$instanceConsumer = ([wmiclass]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:ActiveScriptEventConsumer").CreateInstance()
$instanceConsumer.Name = 'ConsumerNameHere'
$instanceConsumer.ScriptingEngine = 'VBScript'
$instanceConsumer.ScriptFilename = '' 
$instanceConsumer.ScriptText = $script
$instanceConsumer.Put()

# Binding

[object]$Filter = (Get-WMIObject -Computername $Computername -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventFilter | Sort Name)
[object]$Consumer = (Get-WMIObject -Computername $Computername -Namespace root\Subscription -Class __EventConsumer | Sort Name)

$instanceBinding = ([wmiclass]"\\$Computername\root\subscription:__FilterToConsumerBinding").CreateInstance()
$instanceBinding.Filter = $Filter
$instanceBinding.Consumer = $Consumer
$instanceBinding.Put()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach the path of the consumer and filter to the binder
instead of every filter\consumer in the system

```
$result = $instanceFilter.Put()
$filterPath = $result.Path
$result = $instanceConsumer.Put()
$consumerPath = $result.Path

$bind.Filter = $filterPath
$bind.Consumer = $consumerPath
```